# custom post type in wp results in syntax error unexpected endif

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm following this tutorial for custom post types:
http://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/creating-custom-post-types-in-wordpress

I'm using underscore starter wp theme.
http://underscores.me/

I've created a page-movie-reviews.php file with the code bellow, 
but I get a syntax error on the page:
**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF) in C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\prototype\page-movie-reviews.php on line 34**

my code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Movie Reviews
 * @package prototype
 */

get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">




    <div class="entry-content">
     <?php
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
          the_post_thumbnail();
        }
          the_content();
        ?>
    </div>



    <?php $query = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'movie-reviews', 'posts_per_page' => 5 ) );
     while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
    <?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>





            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>

                <?php
                    // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template
                    if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                        comments_template();
                    endif;
                ?>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>








        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: You're using the "curly braces" syntax `If (something) { //code }` which doesn't require the `endif;` statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when using a loop in WP, 
you need to have a condition to check if there are posts that fits your criteria.
I believe you copied it from somewhere else but forgot to copy the condition that comes before the loop. All you need to do is to remove the `endif;` from the following code **or** add a `if($query->have_posts()):` condition before the loop.

**Tip:** Make sure to use indents and break-lines in your code when needed.
That way it would be much easier to locate the problem.

```
<?php
$query = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'movie-reviews', 'posts_per_page' => 5 ) );
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
<?php 
endif; //<-- you can remove this one.
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```